# PHP Class Coupling with Global Settings

Tags: php, class, inversion-of-control

I am in need of some advice with regards to the design pattern I use for a project I am working on. Let's say I have lots of classes which will use dependency injection and IoC containers for instantiation. A lot of these classes will rely on 'environmental' settings, such a memcached class relying on server locations, and SQL classes relying on SQL host details, but I'm not sure how to code this dependency.

I could write these into the class, but it's not flexible. If I make the class utilize a global variable, I feel they are no longer loosely coupled and unit tests will be harder to complete. As such, how can I maintain a loose class coupling but maintain these settings from a central location?

I don't want to have to dig through twelve PHP scripts to change each of the settings if the server setup alters.

Ideally, I would like:

- Centralized settings and configurations
- Classes not implicitly coupled to external entities
- Ability to unit test still!

Cheers!
Adrian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll have to admit that I'm a fan of [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). From what you write, I'd do the following:

Create a configuration class holding your variables:

```
class Configuration {
     protected $sqlUser = "myUser";
     protected $sqlPass = "myPass";
     // ... and the remaining config variables

     public function getSQLUser() {
         return $this->sqlUser();
     }

     public function getSQLPass() {
         return $this->sqlPass;
     }
     // ... and the remaining getters
}
```

This gives you complete control over how you might want to proceed with your configuration in the future. You could e.g., by changing this class,

- read it from a local config file
- generate it depending on the server's machine name (or any other attribute)
- vary it if you're running tests

I do it like this myself. It's enough for what I need, and it avoids architectural skyscraperism.

Comment: Great, thanks Likeitlikeit! And I can use this will Dependency Injection too!

Answer (score 1):

Configuration should never live in your code. It's not the code's "job" to maintain credentials or values to operate, it should be handed these values.

A good read on this, and a solution, is at [The Twelve-Factor App](http://www.12factor.net/config), which will tell you to store these in the environment (*usually environment variables on the server*) and not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
class App {

    public function getConfig($conf_name){
        return new Config($conf_name);
    }
}

class Config {

    private $DB_host = '127.0.0.1';

    function __construct($conf_name){
        //return config
    }

}

class DB extends App {

    public function conn(){
        $this->getConfig('DB');
        //.......
    }
}
```